# Coding sequences by Toeplitz shifts

Tags: dynamical-systems, coding-theory

There is a construction in M. Hochman's paper *Rohlin properties for $\mathbb{Z}^d$ actions on the Cantor set*, Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 364 (2012), no. 3, 1127–1143:

In 5.2: He wants to associate to an element $\omega\in\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ a Toeplitz sequence $z_\omega\in \{0,1\}^\mathbb{Z}$ in the following way: he takes an arithmetic progression in $\mathbb{Z}$ of period 2 passing through 0 and he defines $z_\omega$ on this progression to be equal to $\omega(1)$. Then he takes an arithmetic progression of period 4 passing through 1 and he defines $z_\omega$ to be equal to $\omega(2)$ on this progression. In the general $n$-th step, he takes the unused element of $\mathbb{Z}$ of the least absolute value and an arithmetic progression of period $2^n$ passing through it and he defines $z_\omega$ to be equal to $\omega(n)$ on this progression.

Finally, he takes an orbit closure of $z_\omega$ inside $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{Z}$, denoted by $Z_\omega$, and claims that $\omega$ can be recovered from any element of $Z_\omega$ (in an algortihmically computable way). This seems to be wrong though (unless I miss something trivial). If $\omega(1)=1$ and $\omega(n)=0$ for every $n>1$, then $Z_\omega$ is a periodic shift (of period 2) and it's impossible to recover $\omega$ exactly since $\omega'$ defined by $\omega'(1)=0$ and $\omega'(n)=1$ for $n>1$ defines exactly the same shift.

I have noticed that Toeplitz sequences and the shifts they generate are used for coding sequences, but it seems to me it should be done in a slightly more careful way. Can someone explain this coding?

Comment: can you define explicitly what "orbit closure" is.

Comment: @kodlu The orbit closure of $x\in \{0,1\}^\mathbb{Z}$ is the topological closure of the orbit of $x$ under the shift action - meaning take the set of all (left and right) shifts of $x$ and then take the closure of this set in $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{Z}$ as a topological space.

Comment: I probably figured out how to code $\omega\in\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ by Toeplitz sequences in $\{0,1,2\}^\mathbb{Z}$: Take an arithmetic progression of period 3 passing through 0 and define $z_\omega$ to be equal to $\omega(1)$ on this progression. Take the same progression passing through 1 and define $z_\omega$ to be 2 there. What is unused now is the same progression passing through 2. Take an arithmetic progression of period 9 passing through 2 and set $z_\omega$ to be equal to $\omega(2)$ there. Take the same progression passing through 5 and define $z_\omega$ to be 2 there, etc.